# Flutter pub get acting weird

Tags: flutter

I was trying to do a project I cloned but I cant seem to use any of the packages and when I used the pub get command I get this error[image]

Answer (score 0):

it looks like you edited the pubspec.lock file. pubspec file indent sensitive. you can delete it and run `flutter pub get` to genarate file again.